# Creating a string corresponding to dates

Tags: matlab, graph

I am having difficulty constructing a particular string in MATLAB. I am creating a series of figures and would like the title of each figure to correspond to a particular date. For example, the title of the first figure would be dated as 1st of January 2000 and so on for a set number of years.

I tried to define the days from 1:30, but not every month has 30 days. I am not sure how to proceed.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell if you're looking for [`datestr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) or something else. Can you give us an example of your input data and your desired output?

Comment: @beaker Thanks for your response. I am examining anomalies in global sea surface temperatures from 1981 to the present day. I have created a command that creates a figure displaying this data for each day of this time period. I am now trying to create a command that allows me to create a title, e.g 01-Jan-1981, for each figure. Does that explanation help at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
start_date = datetime(1981, 1, 1); % assuming start date of your data
end_date = datetime('now'); % present date
% creating as datetime vector from start date to present with one day difference so that it takes all days fromdate to todate
fig_titles = start_date:days(1):end_date;
% plotting dummy data([1:100]) as figure 1 
figure(1), plot([1:100]), title(datestr(fig_titles(1))); % convert date to date string
```

Comment: I'm having trouble using this code. If I remove the dummy data, it only displays the date for the first image and no more. Any suggestions?